# How to combine associative arrays with same keys

Tags: php

I am trying to combine these two arrays:

```
Array ( [carrier] => USPS Ground [rate] => 6.00 ) 
Array ( [carrier] => FedEx Ground [rate] => 11.01 )
```

When I use array_merge I get:

```
Array ( [carrier] => FedEx Ground [rate] => 11.01 )
```

since the keys are the same.

When using array_combine you get:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [USPS Ground] => FedEx Ground [6.00] => 11.01 ) )
```

When using array_merge_recursive I get:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [carrier] => Array ( [0] => USPS Ground [1] => FedEx Ground ) [rate] => Array ( [0] => 6.00 [1] => 11.01 ) ) )
```

I am trying to get this as my result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [carrier] => USPS Ground [rate] => 6 ) [1] => Array ( [carrier] => FedEx Ground [rate] => 11.01 ) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use [**`array_push`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) ?

```
array_push($yournewarray,$array1,$array2);
```

Example...

```
<?php
$arr1=Array ( 'carrier' => 'USPS Ground', 'rate' => 6.00 );
$arr2=Array ( 'carrier' => 'FedEx Ground', 'rate' => 11.01 );
$new_array=array();
array_push($new_array,$arr1,$arr2); //You can any number of arrays here, not just two
print_r($new_array);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [carrier] => USPS Ground
            [rate] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [carrier] => FedEx Ground
            [rate] => 11.01
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you Shankar. I did not realize that I could use array_push in a new array. I believe I previously tried array_push($arr1, $arr2) without success.